# Where is Stack Overflow hosted?

Tags: discussion, web-hosting

Where is Stack Overflow hosted?

Is it in its own structure, or is it in some other data center?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It used to be hosted on Peer1 Hosting in the beginning.

These days, as answered in [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) they have their own data centers:

> Host two datacenters:
>
> - New York: QTS (technically in Jersey City, NJ now)
> - Denver: FORTRUST